# Loading in data via Django orm very memory intensive

Tags: python, django, django-orm

So I have a script that loads in data that was created from a python pickle file.

```
dump_file = open('movies.pkl')
movie_data = pickle.load(dump_file)

@transaction.commit_manually
def load_data(data):
    start = False
    counter = 0
    for item in data:
                counter += 1
            film_name = item.decode(encoding='latin1')
            print "at", film_name, str(counter), str(len(data))
            film_rating = float(data[item][0])
            get_votes = int(data[item][2]['votes'])
            full_date = data[item][2]['year']
            temp_film = Film(name=film_name,date=full_date,rating=film_rating, votes=get_votes)
            temp_film.save()
            for actor in data[item][1]:
                actor = actor.decode(encoding='latin1')
                print "adding", actor
                person = Person.objects.get(full=actor)
                temp_film.actors.add(person)
            if counter % 10000 == 0 or counter % len(data) == 0:
                    transaction.commit()
                    print "COMMITED"

load_data(movie_data)
```

So this is a very large data set. And it takes up a lot of memory where it slows down to a crawl, and in the past my solution was to just restart the script from where I left off, so it would take quite a few runs to actually save everything into the database.

I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this (even an optimization in my code would be nice) other than writing raw sql to input the data? I've tried JSON fixtures previously and it was even worse than this method.

Answer (score 1):

If size of movie_data is large, you might wanna divide it into smaller files first and then iterate over them one by one.
Remember to free memory of previously loaded pkl files or keep overwriting the same variable.
If movie data is a list, you can free memory of of say 1000 records after you have iterated over them by slicing such as movie_data=movie_data[1000:] to reduce memory consumption over time

Comment: movie_data is a dict that holds a list of information about each movie, so I may just trying splitting the dict into multiple parts.

Comment: Any particular reason why you are storing this huge dataset in a pickle and not database ?

Comment: Due to the nature of how the data is obtained, it's a lot more convenient for me to gather all the data into a pickle, and then process all that data to be put into a database. In the future I may try to write something that directly loads it into the database, but currently this method is more simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bulk_create() method on the QuerySet object to create mutliple object in a single query, it's available in Django 1.4. Please go through following documentation link -

- Bulk Create - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create

You can also optimize you code, by open the file with "with" keyword in python. "With" statement, it automatically closes the files for you, do all the operations inside the with block, so it'll keep the files open for you and will close the files once you're out of the with block.

Comment: yeah this script was created a while ago when I didn't know about 'with', I'll add that in now. I'll test bulk_create to see if it helps.

Comment: Actually, further reading the documentation it states "It does not work with many-to-many relationships.", which I currently have with my actors and film models.